# Python for VS Code installation problem: "This extension is deprecated as it is no longer being maintained."

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

[image: screenshot of Python for VS Code extension page with a deprecation notice]

> This extension is deprecated as it is no longer being maintained

Why is this message showing? Is it a problem? If so, how can fix it?

Comment: _"why show this message"_ - ...because the extension is deprecated as it is no longer maintained? What's unclear? You already have the official Python extension anyway.

Comment: "*how to fix it*" - By uninstalling it because it is no longer maintained, and installing the official Python extension instead: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

Comment: then most likely there is a replacement that **IS** maintained and has >30M users

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1#discussioncomment-6522702, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76748290/11107541

Answer (score 2):

[I reached out the VS Code maintainers and asked](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1#discussioncomment-6522702) about why the [`tht13.python`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tht13.python) got marked as deprecated- the regular procedure for extension deprecation at the time of this writing is either for the extension maintainer to reach out the VS Code maintainers and ask for the extension to be marked as deprecated, or for another party to ask the VS Code maintainers to reach out the the extension maintainer, but I didn't see paper trails for either of those things happening. [A VS Code maintainer (Isidor Nikolic) replied](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/1#discussioncomment-6526576):

> The VS Marketplace team reached out multiple times to the author - Thomas Haakon Townsend. After 6 months there was no reply, and that in conjunction with the fact that the extension has not been updated in 7+ years we decided to mark it as deprecated.
> If Thomas disagrees he can reach out to us and we can make it to be no longer deprecated.

I suggest that you use the Microsoft Python extension instead: [`ms-python.python`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). Also, I'm pretty sure that deprecation doesn't mean you can't keep using it... so you could also just... keep using it. To my understanding, deprecation usually means "the maintainers are no longer going to be giving support on this thing, and ideally you would move to using some other better thing like it."

Comment: Fo you have a suggestion for a full free extension, too? "The Pylance extension is only available in binary form and is released under a Microsoft proprietary license,"